# Convergence of given sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function with:

$$f(x) = x - \arctan{x}$$

We consider the sequence $(x_{n})$ with $x_{0} > 0$ and $x_{n + 1} = f(x_{n})$, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Prove that $(x_{n})$ is convergent and find its limit.

So far, I've proved that $f(x) \geq 0$ for any $x \geq 0$. From this I've concluded that $(x_{n})$ is a positive sequence. Now I need to find $(x_{n})$'s monotony. I've calculated both $x_{n + 1} - x_{n}$ and $\frac{x_{n + 1}}{x_{n}}$. For the first I've got $- \arctan{x_{n}}$ and the second one gave me $1 - \frac{\arctan{x_{n}}}{x_{n}}$. From this point I don't know what to do next.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: its limit must be 0. for x >0, f(x)<x, then it must approach 0. for x <0, same reason?

Comment: Hint: note that this function is a contraction and use Banach's fixed point theorem.

Comment: I haven't studied contractions yet, so I need a solution without involving contractions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the graph: (from Wolfram Alpha)

[image]

The way to answer this question is to prove that, say for $x > 0$, $f(x) < x \le 0$. It should be clear that iterating the function only gets you closer to zero.

Does this help?

Answer (score -1):

The derivative is $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$and  the function is a contraction mapping on any interval $[0,n]$. The given sequence is used to find the  fixed point x=0.